How do I resolve a sign-in loop in Visual Studio 2022?
I can't sign into Visual Studio 2022. I click Sign in, enter credentials, the progress indicator goes for a little while, and that it says Sign in once again where it should have my user's icon. Here is what I see in the Temp\servicehub\logs log:
04/26/2024 22:52:43 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Failed getting tenant details preferred client exception 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 182
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.GetResponseAsync[TResult](Func`3 hostProvider, Uri apiUri, GraphTokenRequestParameters authParameters, Func`2 transformation, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, Int32 attemptCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String callerName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 112
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.GetResponseAsync[TResult](Func`3 hostProvider, Uri apiUri, GraphTokenRequestParameters authParameters, Func`2 transformation, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, Int32 attemptCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String callerName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 151
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.Graph.GraphClient.AbstractGraphClient.GetTenantDetailsAsync(GraphTokenRequestParameters tokenRequestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\Graph\GraphClient.cs:line 250
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.Graph.GraphClient.GetTenantDetailsAsync(GraphTokenRequestParameters tokenRequestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\Graph\GraphClient.cs:line 71'
04/26/2024 22:52:43 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Failed getting tenant details fallback exception 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Unauthorized to access 'https://graph.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/tenantDetails?api-version=1.6'. Forbidden
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 179
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.GetResponseAsync[TResult](Func`3 hostProvider, Uri apiUri, GraphTokenRequestParameters authParameters, Func`2 transformation, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, Int32 attemptCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String callerName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 112
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.HttpClientWrapper.GetResponseAsync[TResult](Func`3 hostProvider, Uri apiUri, GraphTokenRequestParameters authParameters, Func`2 transformation, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOp, Int32 attemptCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String callerName) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\HttpClientWrapper.cs:line 130
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.Graph.GraphClient.AbstractGraphClient.GetTenantDetailsAsync(GraphTokenRequestParameters tokenRequestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\Graph\GraphClient.cs:line 250
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.Graph.GraphClient.GetTenantDetailsAsync(GraphTokenRequestParameters tokenRequestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\Graph\GraphClient.cs:line 94'
04/26/2024 22:52:43 Eastern Standard Time : Error : Skipping tenant 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a' error getting friendly name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AADAccountProvider.Graph.GraphClient.GetTenantDetailsAsync(GraphTokenRequestParameters tokenRequestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\Graph\GraphClient.cs:line 114
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderNetworkServicesBase.GetTenantDetailsAsync(TenantInformation partialTenantInfo, AuthenticationInfo authInfo, Boolean promptIfNeeded, String queryParameters, AuthenticationFlowType authenticationFlowType, Dictionary`2 additionalAuthProperties, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\AadAccountProviderNetworkServicesBase.cs:line 117
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderService.TryGetTenantDetailsAsync(AuthenticationInfo authInfo, Boolean promptIfNeeded, String queryParameters, AuthenticationFlowType authenticationFlowType, Dictionary`2 additionalAuthProperties, List`1 tenants, HashSet`1 missingTenants, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\IdentityService\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService\AccountProvider\AADAccountProvider\AadAccountProviderService.cs:line 1791'


Judging from the logs, VS 2022 encountered HttpRequestException and UnauthorizedAccessException errors when trying to obtain tenant details. This may be due to network issues, account permission settings, or authentication issues with VS. Here are some possible resolution steps:

Make sure the network connection is stable and there are no firewalls or proxy servers blocking VS connections.
Try deleting all files in the C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local.IdentityService folder, this will clear the authentication cache.
In VS's Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts, change the option of "Add and reauthenticate accounts using" from "Windows authentication broker" to "Embedded web browser".
Run the devenv /ResetSettings command in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022 to reset the settings of VS.

